# similar to an older question "add header to columns from list text file"

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to add some headers to a txt file. Actually i have found a script already but I want to edit a part of it.
Script (you can also find it here if you like: https://ucdavis-bioinformatics-training.github.io/2017-June-RNA-Seq-Workshop/thursday/counts.html):

```
for x in 03-alignment/*/*ReadsPerGene.out.tab; do \
    s=`basename $x | cut -f1 -d_`
    echo $s
done | paste -s > header.txt
```

The thing is that I want to "paste -s" but not starting from the first column but from the second.
I thought done | awk $2 | paste -s | header.txt could help but is doesnt.

Any ideas how to add the headers starting directly from the 2nd column, please?

So using the script above I take this output.

```
L004_AQAU-19 L004_AQAU-20 L004_AQAU-21 etc. 
ALOMY0G001 0 0 
ALOMY0G002 0 10 
ALOMY0G003 20 15 
ALOMY0G004 4 5 etc.
```

But i want to take the

```
        L004_AQAU-19  L004_AQAU-20  etc.
ALOMY0G001  0   0   
ALOMY0G002  0   10
ALOMY0G003  20  15
ALOMY0G004  4   5
etc.
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with related expected output. Don't post them as images or comments but edit them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `cut` to get a range from a tab delimited line of words.

```
... paste -s | cut -f2- > header.txt
```

If you want to skip the first column, (don't have a header on the first column, just introduce an empty tab at the start.

```
... paste -s | sed 's/^/\t/' > header.txt
```

Here I use `sed` to replace something. You can replace like `s/A/B/g` where it replaces A with B. (The g indicates if this has to be done more than once per line.) These "patterns" are regular expressions (regex). For regex `^` is the beginning of  the line. So here, I replace `^` (the beginning of the line) with `\t` (a tab). (`paste` uses tab by default, use `paste -d, -s` for example to use a comma.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Hielke for your answer, but like this i lose the first header L004_AQAU-19, so basically the header paste starts from the 2nd header on. What i want is the first header to start from the 2nd column and on.

Comment: @Bia You might want to post example data next time, just like James Brown mentioned in a comment on the OP.

Comment: i edited my question..it took me some time to do it properly bcs I am new here. And i tried your second code and is working! Thank you sooo much!! :) Could you please as well explain me what the symbols  's/^/\t/' mean here??